# Neither the property "commentaire" nor one of the methods exist and have public access in class

Tags: symfony, orm

I'm currently building a blog using Symfony 3 
I have 2 major class
Article -> With my blog articles

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Titre", type="text")
 */
private $titre;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="article", type="text")
 */
private $article;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_article", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateArticle;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Commentaire_blog", mappedBy="article")
 */
private $commentaires;


public function __construct($commentaires)
{
    $this->commentaires = $commentaires;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCommentaires()
{
    return $this->commentaires;
}



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set titre
 *
 * @param string $titre
 *
 * @return Article
 */
public function setTitre($titre)
{
    $this->titre = $titre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titre
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitre()
{
    return $this->titre;
}

/**
 * Set article
 *
 * @param string $article
 *
 * @return Article
 */
public function setArticle($article)
{
    $this->article = $article;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get article
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getArticle()
{
    return $this->article;
}

/**
 * Set dateArticle
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateArticle
 *
 * @return Article
 */
public function setDateArticle($dateArticle)
{
    $this->dateArticle = $dateArticle;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateArticle
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateArticle()
{
    return $this->dateArticle;
}


}
```

Commentaire_blog -> With comments from my blog.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Commentaire_blog
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="commentaire_blog")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Commentaire_blogRepository")
 */
class Commentaire_blog
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="usernamne", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $usernamne;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text")
 */
private $message;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_visible", type="boolean")
 */
private $isVisible;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getArticle()
{
    return $this->article;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $article
 */
public function setArticle($article)
{
    $this->article = $article;
}

/*
 * @ORM\ManytoOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="commentaires")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $article;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set usernamne
 *
 * @param string $usernamne
 *
 * @return Commentaire_blog
 */
public function setUsernamne($usernamne)
{
    $this->usernamne = $usernamne;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get usernamne
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsernamne()
{
    return $this->usernamne;
}

/**
 * Set message
 *
 * @param string $message
 *
 * @return Commentaire_blog
 */
public function setMessage($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get message
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMessage()
{
    return $this->message;
}

/**
 * Set isVisible
 *
 * @param boolean $isVisible
 *
 * @return Commentaire_blog
 */
public function setIsVisible($isVisible)
{
    $this->isVisible = $isVisible;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isVisible
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getIsVisible()
{
    return $this->isVisible;
}

}
```

And I have have this error when I want to show my page :

> Neither the property "commentaire" nor one of the methods "getCommentaire()", "commentaire()", "isCommentaire()", "hasCommentaire()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Commentaire_blog".

I don't understand the problem... So if some one can explain me What happen it will be nice.

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this two methods to the **one** end class `Article`:

```
/**
 * Add a Commentaire_blog to this Article
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Commentaire_blog $commentaireBlog
 */
public function addCommentaire(Commentaire_blog $commentaireBlog)
{
    if (!$this->commentaires->contains($commentaireBlog)) {
        $this->commentaires->add($commentaireBlog);
    }
}

/**
 * Remove, if exists, a Commentaire_blog from this Article
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Commentaire_blog $commentaireBlog
 */
public function removeCommentaire(Commentaire_blog $commentaireBlog)
{
    if ($this->commentaires->contains($commentaireBlog)) {
        $this->commentaires->removeElement($commentaireBlog);
    }
}
```

I recommend you edit the `Article->commentaires` property to this, to allow `Article` class to create, remove and edit commentaires related to it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Commentaire_blog", mappedBy="article",
 *     cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}
 * )
 */
private $commentaires;
```

**EDIT**

Try to add this method to the `Article` class. Do not forget add the above methods too, realize I have changed the name of the methods above.

```
/**
 * Get a Commentaire_blog of this Article
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Commentaire_blog $commentaireBlog
 */
public function GetCommentaire(Commentaire_blog $commentaireBlog)
{
    if (!$this->commentaires->contains($commentaireBlog)) {
        return $this->commentaires->get($commentaireBlog);
    }
}
```

Comment: I(ve tried to change What you say but the error still stay here.

Comment: @Newbiedev look at the update of my answer. Take special attention to the name of all methods.

Answer (score 1):

A `OneToMany` relationship has to be bidirectional or use a join table as stated in [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

> A one-to-many association has to be bidirectional, unless you are
>   using a join table. This is because the many side in a one-to-many
>   association holds the foreign key, making it the owning side. Doctrine
>   needs the many side defined in order to understand the association.

That means you have to define a `ManyToOne` relationship on `Commentaire_blog->commentaire` or declare `Article->commentaire` as `ManyToMany` relationship using a join table as described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Commentaire_blog")
 * @JoinTable(name="articles_commentaireblogs",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="commentaire_blog_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 */
private $commentaires;
```

Comment: Then could you share the piece of code which throws that error?